# TEXT within Grid container NOT RESPONSIVE

Tags: responsive, css-grid

I can't figure out why the text within the grid boxes (containers) isn't adapting to the size of the screen.

I've tried using wv, @media, but the problem persists.
The site I'm creating this page for only works with CSS, HTML and Java

```css
p /* style for paragraphs */{
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 1em;
  }
 h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.67em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}
li.spaced {
  height: 10px;
  width: 144px;
  float: left;
}
#circle /* big circle that goes around text */{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: moccasin;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
  font: 14px Arial, sans-serif;
}
#circle2 /* smaller circle that goes around text */{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: peachpuff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  font: 18px Arial, sans-serif;
}
#highlight /* to highlight important info */{
  padding: 2px;
  background: peachpuff;
}
.boxtext /* this is to create a box around text w/thick line */{
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.boxtext2  /* this is to create a box around text w/thin line */{
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.smallboxtext/* this is the end of the box around text */{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F9E79F;
  width: auto;
  border: 0px solid orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.green /* this is to write colored text */{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #229954;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.red  {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #FF0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.blue  {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #3498DB;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.purple /* end of colored text */ {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #8E44AD;
  font-weight: bold;
}
table /* info for tables */{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid rgb(200,200,200);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}
tbody {
  font-size: 95%;
  font-style: italic;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
th {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
.container /* this creates a small/centered container around sections */{
  width: 50%;
}
#wrapper /* this creates a wide container around sections */{
  max-width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#wrapperGRID /* this creates a RESPONSIVE GRID for 1 2 3 */{
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  
}
.containNumber /* this a subdiv for number BOXED ELEMENTS */ {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 4em;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#subDiv /* this a subdiv for elements */ {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 15px 20px 20px;
}
#subDiv1 {
  width: 40%;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-left: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 40px 15px 20px 15px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
#subDiv2 /* this div is used for inserting brackets */{
  width: 3%;
  float: left;
}
#subDiv3 {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#subDiv4 {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 15px 20px 20px;
}
.bracketfulleft /* this is the bracket used in personal pronouns */{
  width: 15px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: 0;
}
.bracketfullright /* this is the bracket used in personal pronouns */{
  width: 15px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-right: 0;
}
.bracketbottomleft /* this is the bracket used in personal pronouns */{
  width: 15px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
.bracketbottomright /* this is the bracket used in personal pronouns */{
  width: 15px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}
.bracketupleft /* this is the bracket used in personal pronouns */{
  width: 15px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.bracketupright /* this is the bracket used in personal pronouns */{
  width: 15px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.smtext /* for the smalles print text inside div */{
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.medtext /* for smaller print text inside div */{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.bg-text /* to create a big text wataermark box */{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee801e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #ee801e, #e75b10);
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg-text::after /* text inside watermark box */{
  content: attr(data-bg-text);
  display: block;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee801e;
  opacity: 0.1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #ee801e, #e75b10);
}
.vl /* for vertical lines */{
  border-left: 5px solid orange;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
hr.dotted /* for dotted vertical lines */{
  border-top: 1px dashed orange;
}
.arrow::after /* to add arrow gliph */{
  content: ' \2192';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #000;
}
.arrowDOWN::after /* to add arrow gliph */{
  content: ' \2193';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #000;
}
.arrowUP::after /* to add arrow gliph */{
  content: ' \2191';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  p {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  p {
    font-size: 19px;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 31px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 33px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperGRID">
  
  <div style="grid-column: 1 / 3; grid-row: 1 / -1;">
    <u>Pregunta 1:</u>
    <div class="arrowDOWN"></div>
      <i>¿Quién hace<br> la acción?</i>
        <div class="containNumber">1<br>
        <p class="smtext">un pronombre</p></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
<div style="grid-column: 4 / 7; grid-row: 1 / -1;">
  <u>Pregunta 2:</u>
    <div class="arrowDOWN"></div>
      <i>¿Cuál es<br> la acción?</i>
         <div class="containNumber">2<br>
        <p class="smtext">un verbo</p></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
  
  <div style="grid-column: 8 / -1; grid-row: 1 / -1;">
  <u>Pregunta 3:</u>
    <div class="arrowDOWN" style="width: 90%"></div>
      <i>¿Quién recibe<br> la acción?</i>
         <div class="containNumber">3<br>
        <p class="smtext">info adicional</p></div>
      <div style="text-size:10px; width: 90%";>Podemos usar 
      <span id="highlight">más de una mini-pregunta</span>, siempre que
      tenga sentido.<br><i>Por ejemplo:</i>
      </div>
      <div class="arrowDOWN" style="width: 90%"></div>

      <ul id="highlight" style="list-style-type:none; width: 90%";>
        <li >¿qué/quién?</li>
        <li>¿con quién?</li>
        <li>¿para quién?</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
  </div><br><br>
        
<div id="wrapperGRID">

    <div style="grid-column: 1 / 3; grid-row: 1 / 2;">
      Ej. 1:
      </div>


  <div style="grid-column: 4 / 6; grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <div class="containNumber">1</div>
      <p>She</p>
      <p>He</p>
      <p>We</p>
  </div>
 
  
  <div style="grid-column: 6 / 7; grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <hr  class="dotted">
  </div>
    
  
  <div style="grid-column: 7 / 9;  grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <div class="containNumber">2</div>
      <p>is cooking</p>
      <p>is eating</p>
      <p>cooked</p>
  </div>
    
  <div style="grid-column: 9 / 10; grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <hr  class="dotted">
  </div>
   
  
   <div style="grid-column: 10/ 12;  grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <div class="containNumber">3</div>
        <p style="width:90%">eggs.</p>
        <p>with them.</p>
        <p style="width:90%">for my mom.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapperGRID">

    <div style="grid-column: 1 / 3; grid-row: 1 / 2; font-size: 30px">
      Ejemplo 2:
      </div>


  <div style="grid-column: 3 / 4; grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <div class="containNumber">1</div>
      <p style="width:90%">Sfghfghfghfgh</p>
      <p style="width:90%">fghfghfgh</p>
      <p style="width:90%">fgfghfgh</p>
  </div>
 
  
  <div style="grid-column: 4 / 5; grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <hr  class="dotted">
  </div>
    
  
  <div style="grid-column: 5 / 7;  grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <div class="containNumber">2</div>
      <p style="width:90%">is cooking</p>
      <p style="width:90%">is eating</p>
      <p style="width:90%">cooked</p>
  </div>
    
  <div style="grid-column: 7 / 8; grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <hr  class="dotted">
  </div>
   
  
   <div style="grid-column: 8/ 10;  grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <div class="containNumber">3</div>
        <p style="width:90%">eggs.</p>
        <p style="width:90%">with them.</p>
        <p style="width:90%">for my mom.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div style="grid-column: 10 / 12;  grid-row: 1 / 2;">
    <div class="containNumber">3</div>
        <p style="width:90%">eggs.</p>
        <p style="width:90%">with them.</p>
        <p style="width:90%">for my mom.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm relatively new to coding and feeling quite lost right now.
HELP...thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry.... the text within my grid is not reponsive. I need it to adapt to the size of the container it's in so that when the screen is smaller, it doesn't overflow.
Hope that clarifies it :)

Comment: You can't do that with CSS

Comment: How can I do it then? With what type of code? Any guidance, much appreciated.